# Is there a way to auto format modified code in Visual Studio Code (VS code)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just discovered the <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>f</kbd> (for mac user) and it's very helpfull.
But somehow, I would like to know if there is a way to automate the code format at save for the added/modified code.

I dont want to do it on the whole file because it's gonna uglify the git history on modified blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use "Prettier-Code formatter" extension. you just press 'ctrl+s'(for linux) and "command + s"(for mac) to format the file that you want to format. It will format code when you want to format. I still use auto save mode. I think it's very useful.

Comment: This is the plugin I'm using, but like I said I want it to format only the block I'm working on not the whole file, automaticly.
I could select the block code and format it, but I would like to gain time on this task.